# Problema com CSS com url amigavel

Tags: html, css, url-amigável

Galera, eu estou estudando urls amigáveis e me deparei com um problema. Toda vez que coloco uma / (barra) no final da url, o css some e a página fica com html puro.
Gostaria de entender o que está acontecendo e arrumar. Segue abaixo as imagens para melhor compreensão.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse problema vai ocorrer, porque quando você coloca a barra, o `htaccess` vai tratar aquela `string` como uma pasta.

Comment: entendi, no caso então toda vez que eu linkar o css eu tenho que fazer o caminho /meusite/css/arquivo.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor solução *(dependendo da sua aplicação)* é usar a tag `base` do HTML5.

```
<base href="http://seusite.com/" target="_blank">
```

Veja um exemplo no site da [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_base_test).

Outro método é você obter a pasta root do sistema e jogá-lo numa constante. Como você não mostrou qual linguagem server side está usando, irei mostrar o exemplo em PHP.

```
<?php

define("ROOT", __DIR__); //obtém pasta root
```

Dai no seu código você usa

```
<img src="<?=ROOT?>/stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" alt="Stickman">
```

Existem ainda vários outros exemplos, mas acredito que esses possam ser o suficiente para sanar sua dúvida e lhe ajudar.

Comment: obrigado, é em php mesmo. Deu certo aqui. Muito obrigado!